# bootstrap popover in asp.net webform

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

i would like to try bootstrap pop over using asp.net
ive already tried and search for the ways to do this

> function pageLoad(sender, args) {
>               $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
>                   html: true,
>                   placement: "bottom",
>                   content: function () {
>                       return $('#PopoverConditionMasterPart').html();
>                   }
>               });
>           };
>   but still there's no clear sign for popover.

and in my debugger i see errors like $ is not defined and .popover is not a function

another problem is most of the tutorial is in MVC

can someone give me advise or better explanation to do this.

Thanks in advance and keep going!

here is my current work:

css:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="css" runat="server">
<link href="Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</asp:Content>
```

html:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="body" runat="server">
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2 col-lg-2">
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:Label runat="server" data-toggle="popover" data-placement='bottom' title="sample" ID="lblConditionMasterPart" CssClass="form-control popover PopoverConditionMasterPart" Text="click me" Style="cursor: pointer;"></asp:Label>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel9" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <div id="PopoverConditionMasterPart" style="display: none;">
                    <button type= "button" title="bnt1" class="form-control btn btn-secondary"> btn1</button>  
                    <button type= "button" title="bnt1" class="form-control btn btn-primary"> btn2</button>            
                </div>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </div>
</div>
</asp:Content>
```

script:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content4" ContentPlaceHolderID="script" runat="server">
<script src="Scripts/jquery-3.2.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    function pageLoad(sender, args) {
        $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
            html: true,
            placement: "bottom",
            content: function () {
                return $('#PopoverConditionMasterPart').html();
            }
        });
    };
</script>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: For starters, do you have that code inside a <script> tag? Then check your bundling to make sure you have jquery and bootstrap.js loaded.

Comment: Hi steeve, yes i use the script tag but in the bundling i dont have idea how i can check it, i just drag and drop the link of my .js and .css into my forms and i think its loaded because my bootsrap modal is working properly only the popover is my problem. by the way aside from stack overflow i already refer to this tutorial but nothing works properly. Thanks for your help i really appreciate it.
http://www.webcodeexpert.com/2016/02/examples-to-use-bootstrap-popover-in.html

https://aspdotnetcodehelp.wordpress.com/bootstrap-popover-an-overview/

Comment: Edit you question and show the javascript as it is in your page. You should have it inside `$(document).ready()`. Also, show the control you want to have the popover.

Comment: @SteveGreene please check my update, I already tried to put _$(document).ready_ I'm not sure if done it correctly

Comment: check it here:
`<script src="Scripts/jquery-3.2.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function pageLoad(sender, args) {
            $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
                html: true,
                placement: "bottom",
                content: function () {
                    return $('#PopoverConditionMasterPart').html();
                }});
        });
</script>`

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are defining a pageLoad function but never calling it. You could call it in ready, but why not just do what the function does on page load:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(document).ready(

        $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({ 
            html: true, 
            placement: "bottom", 
            content: function () { 
                         return $('#PopoverConditionMasterPart').html(); 
                      }
            }); 
     }); 
</script>
```

Comment: I already tried your code but then there's still no popover showing and another this there must be some problem on the script, instead I come with this

`$(document).ready(function() {`
`$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({`
                `html: true,`
                `content: function () {`
                    `return $('#PopoverConditionMasterPart').html();`
                `}`
            `});`
`});`